# Multiline math mode inside a Node doesn't work at all

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, nodes

I would like to draw a picture and write some equations below it that will be aligned to a certain symbol ( the equal sign in this case ).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] (square) {};
        \node[below=of square] () {$
        Area &= side \times side \\
        Perimeter &= 4 \times side
        $}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: Math mode has nothing to do with it, you cannot use ``\\`` in a note without it explicitly having a width.

Comment: Besides, you code does not compile at all. `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `of' (in 'of square').`, which has nothing to do with the contents of the node, but rather the placement of the node.

Comment: You're missing `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` and there is a `;` missing on the last node

Comment: What exactly is `$
        Area &= side \times side \\
        Perimeter &= 4 \times side
        $` suppose to do? Those `&` requires an alignment environment, you did not provide one. Perhaps you mean `$
          \begin{aligned}
        Area &= side \times side \\
        Perimeter &= 4 \times side
        \end{aligned}$`

Comment: @daleif forgot that, but still not compiling, my IDE says that lualatex is complaining about the `Misplaced alignment tab character &` not PGF. Anyhow, how can I solve this, or obtain the same result in another way.

Comment: See the other comment and my (or Zarkos) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- in-line math had not be broken into more lines. In your case math expression had to be in `multlined` environment defined in the `amsmath` and `mathtools`
- for positioning you use `positioning` library but not load it

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] (square) {};
\node[below=of square]  
    {$\begin{aligned}
        Area        & = side \times side \\
        Perimeter   & = 4 \times side
      \end{aligned}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: believe it or not, I tried the `aligned`environment before but I placed before the dollar sign ... Anyhow it works now, and I now understand .

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in the code provided.

- The `below=of ...` syntax required the `positioning` tikz lib
- the node with the math is missing a `;` after it
- the contents of the math node uses `&=` but no alignment env which causes en error.

This compiles

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4] (square) {};
        \node[below=of square] {$
          \begin{aligned}
        Area &= side \times side \\
        Perimeter &= 4 \times side
        \end{aligned}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```